# 50000 rows update with one-by-one single line update queries for over 2 hours. What happens if I stop executing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 50K lines of one-by-one query to update records like following:

```
update X_Table set Col1 = 0 where RefId = 1603
update X_Table set Col1 = 2 where RefId = 1604
update X_Table set Col1 = 4 where RefId = 1605
```

etc....

I can already see the records are properly updated in the table. What happends if I stop executing? Will it roll back to original state or what?

Comment: Are they inside a transaction? Whats the complete script you are running?

Comment: @DaleK the full script is the continuation of RefIds (50000 such update statements) . It is not inside transaction . Just one-by-one

Comment: If thats all and there is no transaction, then there will be no rollback.

Comment: Each update statement is its own implicit transaction, each one will have committed prior to executing the next one, there will be no transaction to roll back; if you kill it, it will just stop and the last update statement it was executing will roll back.

Comment: when you have a transaction and it stops, it will return back to the original, without all rows are upodated till you stopped the script

Comment: here is what it looks like : https://paste.pics/PNCEV

Comment: @DaleK I wonder what is it executing then if I can already see the data is updated properly?

Comment: @Stu do you think i can confidently stop executing? What is it executing actually?

Comment: You have confirmed that all 50,000 rows have been correctly updated? I would assume its updated the ones you have checked but is still updating the others.

Comment: @DaleK I can easily say it is done with update .

Comment: We can't advise you whether you are safe to stop executing, if it says its still executing then something is happening, and the situation must be more complex than you describe.

Comment: This is however not the best way to perform this type of action, you should insert the data into a temp table and run a single update, possibly if you're experiencing a hang (?) it's due to the network traffic and resources being consumed by SSMS - hopefully you do not have execution plans turned on. If you have `set nocount off` SSMS will be receiving and displaying additional statement completion text for *every* update

Comment: @DaleK I may assume it is trying to wrap up or just trying to rebuild the index? not sure

Comment: You can't assume anything, nor can we advise you without having more information.

Comment: @Stu obviously I dont have execution plan turned on and I dont have access to view server state to check deadlocks . but I am not sure what it is executing right now.

Comment: @DaleK thanks a lot . I will check if this goes yet another hour . if it still goes on, perhaps I can stop it and see if everything is okay or not.

Comment: *obviously I dont have execution plan turned on* - It's not obvious (why would it be?) and a common cause of SSMS hanging or mem leaks for large batches. Even so, 50k updates from SSMS is almost certainly a red flag.

Comment: quite honestly, I did not expect it take this long hence did not turn on execution plan. Is there a way you may suggest to check memory leaks for ssms ? @Stu

Comment: Open another session and check what your updating SPID is doing - use *sp_who2* or *sp_WhoIsActive*

Comment: @Stu unfortunately I dont have access to sp_whoIsActive , but i just stopped and saw everything looks good and everything was already updated .